# Chi-Squared Test for independence says reject $H_0$, but coefficients say otherwise?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I have some data set. I'm interested in checking for independence or lack of. I've calculated the Chi-squared statistic which is 5,43759, and it has df=1. So, I should reject for a dimension of $\alpha=0.05$.

However, if I calculate the Tschuprow (=Cramér, since cols=rows), I get a value 0.163517. They seem to indicate not to reject the null.

Is this "kosher"(fine)? Maybe I'm just interpreting the coefficients in wrong way...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think Tschuprow's t is contradicting the results from the chi-square test? As you know, Tschuprow's test produces a value between 0 and 1. Given that, you haven't said what you've done to evaluate this result.

Comment: @DJohnson Thanks for your comment. What do you propose I do to evaluate the Tschuprow coefficient? I've already computed its value...

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in a test of significance of the result, correct?

Comment: @DJohnson Correct.

Comment: @DJohnson I need a bit more to go on... I'm self-learning this.

Comment: Dig up the Wiki article on this test. It references the original 1939 work by Tschuprow. If you can't figure it out from there, try another more easily derived test to cross-validate the first result

Comment: Could you explain why you think a T value of $0.163517$ tells you not to reject the null hypothesis?  Exactly what alternative hypothesis test are you applying here?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. The alternative is that at least one of the probabilities doesn't decompose in the usual way, P(AUB) = P(A) P(B).  A T close to zero is seems to imply that most of the data shows independence(P(AUB) = P(A) P(B)), i.e. not to reject the null.

Comment: I meant $P(A\cap B)$